# RuntimeErorr in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I work on my pet project, online library. I write tests for routes. When running the tests, two of them succeed, and the third "test_get_authors" throws a RuntimeError: The current Flask app is not registered with this 'SQLAlchemy' instance. Did you forget to call 'init_app', or did you create multiple 'SQLAlchemy' instances?

How to fix this error?

```
**conftest.py:**
import pytest
from flask import Flask
from routes import blueprint, login_manager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def app():
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="../templates")
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///" + "../instance/test_db.db"
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret_key'
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    return app

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def db(app):
    db = SQLAlchemy(app=app)`
    return db

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


**test_routes.py:**
def test_get_registration_form(client):
    response = client.get('/registration')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b'<!DOCTYPE html>' in response.data
        

def test_get_home(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b'<!DOCTYPE html>' in response.data
    assert b'class="login-form' in response.data


def test_get_authors(client):
    response = client.get('/authors')
    assert b'<!DOCTYPE html>' in response.data

**routes.py:**
@blueprint.route('/authors', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_authors():
    form = AuthorForm()
    authors = Author.query.all()
    return render_template("authors.html", authors=authors, form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be simple. I got rid of the db fixture. Then I imported the database (db) from the application models. After that, I initialized the database object in the application fixture (app).

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from flask import Flask
from routes import blueprint, login_manager
from models import db


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def app():
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="../templates")
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///" + "../instance/library.db"
    app.config["DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS"] = False
    app.config["TESTING"] = True
    app.secret_key = "alkator"
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    app.debug = True
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()
```